# Exclude One Mails in Catch All Default Routing rule in Google Workspace

Tags: google-workspace, catch-all

I am administering Google Workspace email service and I had a catch all done for the delivery of all mails sent to non exiting mailboxes to go in one specific mail box. I've did this with Default Routing rule.

Now I need to reroute support@domain.com mail to external Help Desk system. I've did a default routing rule and it is working, but the global catch rule is catching also the support@domain.com mails.

Can you suggest how I can exclude the support mails?

I've tried to do the support mails with routing, but the default rule still catches them.